# Postgres variadic function to add multiple rows

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, variadic

I am trying to insert multiple rows into my table 'stuff' from an array. Below is my function. The problem I have is that by using the table stuff[] as the type of _stuff_array it is expecting a primary key as the initial value - as the stuff table has one. Is it possible to circumvent that? Or, is it possible to set the types to be expected in the array in the function declaration? If so, how?

Many thanks

Function definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION up_tbl_variadic(VARIADIC _stuff_array stuff[])
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO stuff        (
            X,
            Y
        )
      SELECT *
   FROM unnest(_stuff_array);
END;
$$;
```

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stuff
(
    "id"            BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    "X"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Y"    TEXT NOT NULL
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
```

Comment: Example call:

```SELECT up_tbl_variadic(
 array[
 'stuff',
 'morestuff'
 ]
)
```

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "stuff"

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: Yes you're quite right. Will address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to only select the columns for which you want the values to be inserted:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION up_tbl_variadic(VARIADIC _stuff_array stuff[])
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO stuff("X","Y")
  SELECT x, y
  FROM unnest(_stuff_array) as t(id, x, y);
END;
$$;
```

You declared the parameter as `variadic` so you shouldn't pass an array, but a list of records. And you need to create a three column record for each row you want to pass

So the following will insert two rows

```
SELECT up_tbl_variadic((null, 'stuff', 'morestuff'), 
                       (null, 'otherstuff', 'stuff again'));
```

Comment: Hi. Firstly thank you very much for your reply. Can you please confirm how I should then be executing this function? I am still getting:

SELECT up_tbl_variadic(  array[  'stuff',  'morestuff'  ] )  ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "stuff"

Comment: And also where you put t(id, x, y) is that id needed if the array itself will not contain an id?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I explained my question well. The array will not have IDs, but the stuff[] table expects an ID which is why (I think) it's failing.

Comment: The `id` column will be generated if you don't specify it in the target list. But you need to provide proper record types. See my edit

Comment: Thank you once again. Is there any way to debug this, such as show the contents of _stuff_array? I'm still getting an issue invalid input syntax for integer: "stuff". It would be great to see the contents of "t" also. So the problem definitely isn't VARIADIC _stuff_array stuff[]?

Comment: Did you provide **three** fields for each record parameter?

Comment: Your examples are working. I am trying to translate it into non-pseudo code now.

Comment: Each record parameter that you pass to the function must specify as many fields as the table has columns in the the correct order. The error message suggests that you are providing a string value for a field that is defined as an integer.

Comment: BINGO. "The function must specify as many fields as the table has columns in the the correct order". Thank you so much a_horse_with_no_name!